# UISearchController always display scope bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am adding a search controller in my app  that is part of a tab bar controller. I am trying to get the scope to always show, not just when the search bar is active. I have tried subclassing and overriding the method to always show it, and I have even tried using a UISearchBar and UISegmentedControl separate to seem like the scope is always showing. The issue with that is that the navigation bar height won't change. What would be the best/easiest way of doing this?

(also, for people who have used UISearchController, how can I get the background to extend under the status bar when the UISearchBar is active, like in the mail app)